# CollectionView Segue finding nil on receiving ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a collection view that is selecting an Item in its index and performing a segue to the next ViewController. When the next ViewController is presented, the value of my object is `nil`.

Here is the call in the collectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let adViewVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: adViewPageID) as? AdViewPageVC else {return}
    let adChoice = adArray[indexPath.row]
    adViewVC.advertisement = adChoice
    performSegue(withIdentifier: adViewPageSegue, sender: self)
}
```

Note that the guard statement is going through and if I print a value from the adArray it has value in this function.

After I perform the segue which does open the right ViewController the advertisement object is always nil.

```
var advertisement : Advertisement!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let title = advertisement.title
    print(title)

}
```

This is never getting the value of the object even when I can see that it has value during the assignment on the `didSelectItem` function for the collection view.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I will vote to close this now that it is solved. I am unsure if this specific question is asked elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user taps on the collectionViewCell, the app should perform segue with an `indexPath` as a sender:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: adViewPageSegue, sender: indexPath)
}
```

And prepare all of neccessary things in the `prepare(for:sender:)` method. And you don't have to init a viewController from the storyboard. `segue.destination` is enough.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == adViewPageSegue {
            guard let adViewVC = segue.destination as? AdViewPageVC else {return}
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
            let adChoice = adArray[indexPath.row]
            adViewVC.advertisement = adChoice
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying and will let you know.

Comment: Still finding nil. Debugged it through and it is holding a value all the way to the point of setting our adViewVC.advertisement = adChoice.

Comment: But when we arrive, it is still nil when I try to access it.

Comment: With the solution provided, this should be working correct? I cant figure out what is stopping it up.

Comment: Let change this line `guard  let adViewVC = segue.destination as! AdViewPageVC else {return}`. Is it working?

Comment: THAT DID THE TRICK

Comment: Go ahead and update your answer and I will mark it as correct! Any idea why this worked and the other way didnt?

Comment: I see you used segue to goto another viewController. That's no need to init a viewController from the storyboard. `segue.destination` is that you need.

Comment: Your God's gift to this earth Danh. I was stuck for about an hour trying to see what was wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting the `advertisement` variable in a `prepare(for:sender:)` function. The view controller that you are creating in the didSelect function is not being used.

Add something like this:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destination as? PlayerViewController {
        let adChoice = adArray[sender]
        viewController.advertisement = sender as? STZMediaItem
    }
}
```

And update your didSelect function to be:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: adViewPageSegue, sender: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: let me give it a go!

Comment: Is the medium sized item needed?

Comment: It has a fair amount of data

Comment: Will throw you an upvote for getting me closer to the answer. @Danh Huynh found the issue.